# How do I add meta tags from a template?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, header, meta-tags

I'm developing a website using WordPress as my Framework. The templates are highly customized and really doesn't use much of Wordpress's features. I just use it for registering users and publish a few articles here and there.

One of the templates is a product template. In this template I retrieve product information based on product ID sent in the URL.

What I want to do, is to take info from this product and add it to my `<meta>` tags.

According to [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview), headers are loaded before templates.

So, how can I add meta tag information based on data loaded in my template?

Do I have to query the database "a second time" in the header in order to retrieve the data wanted?

I know Wordpress has some functionality for this, since article titles can be retrieved in the header file. But I'm not sure how I can take advantage of this.

Comment: this may lead you in the right direction http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though header is loaded before template, few global variable are available even before header is loaded and `$post` is one of them which hold post data + metadata.

So you can access post meta in header as well.

```
global $post;
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ur_meta_key', true);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a custom template with data retrieved from a different database. So I'm not using $post. But can I define my own global variables and use them?

Comment: OK. . . still few things are not clear, but as per my understanding you can use WP's init action to define your custom global variables, which is invoked at very initial stage of page load, and you can fetch that global variables values at 'wp_head' action which is invoked just before the closing of HTML head tag (</head>).

Comment: Well, not really - I testet using global vars before I saw your reply comment. But since you're the only answer, I'll give you a point :)